# Extend extra image size ( not resize ) with white background?

Tags: php, image-processing

Lets says user upload image to my site to whatever size... now I want to extend the image ( not resize ). So that i can put some caption/watermark on that extended space.

How can i achive this or pointing me to some specific function will be useful either.

Just for an example . like this image he put watermark and other detail in the bottom.
http://taklong.com/landscape/A/237492DSCN0029.JPG

Thank You and Regards

Comment: http://diceattack.wordpress.com/2011/01/03/combining-multiple-images-using-php-and-gd/ There's a lot to it, and I'm not interested in reading up on it, sorry. It should answer your question fairly well though.

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/book.image.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it making use of the [GD library of PHP](http://php.net/manual/en/book.image.php).

It can be done using `imagecreatetruecolor`, `imagecreatefrompng` (or, JPG or whatever format you use for your watermark)  and `imagecopyresized`.

For example: http://php.net/manual/en/image.examples-watermark.php